# Idiomatic Go Happy Path

Tags: go, idioms

Suppose we have a function that returns some value and an error. What's the preferred way of handling the error and value declarations?

```
func example_a(data interface{}) (interface{}, error) {
    var err error
    var bytes []byte
    if bytes, err = json.Marshal(data); err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    // ... 
    return use(bytes), nil
}

func example_b(data interface{}) (interface{}, error) {
    if bytes, err := json.Marshal(data); err != nil {
        return nil, err
    } else {
        // ... 
        return use(bytes), nil
    }
}

func example_c(data interface{}) (result interface{}, err error) {
    var bytes []byte
    if bytes, err = json.Marshal(data); err != nil {
        return
    }
    // ... 
    return use(bytes), nil
}

func example_d(data interface{}) (interface{}, error) {
    bytes, err := json.Marshal(data)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    // ... 
    return use(bytes), nil
}

func example_dream(data interface{}) (interface{}, error) {
    if bytes, err ≡ json.Marshal(data); err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    // ... 
    return use(bytes), nil
}
```

**Example A** is clear, but it adds 2 extra lines. Moreover, I find that it's unclear why in this particular case we should use `var`, and at the same time `:=` is not always appropriate. Then you want to reuse the `err` declaration somewhere down the line, and I'm not a big fan of splitting declaration and assignment.

**Example B** is using the if-declare-test language feature, which I surmise is encouraged, but at the same time you are forced to nest function continuation violating the happy-path principle, which too is encouraged.

**Example C** uses the named parameter return feature, which is something between A and B. Biggest problem here, is that if your code base is using styles B and C, then it's easy to mistake `:=` and `=`, which can cause all kinds of issues.

**Example D** (added from suggestions) has for me the same kind of usage problem as C, because inevitably I run into the following:

```
func example_d(a, b interface{}) (interface{}, error) {
    bytes, err := json.Marshal(a)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    bytes, err := json.Marshal(b) //Compilation ERROR
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    // ... 
    return use(bytes), nil
}
```

So depending on previous declarations I have to modify my code to either use `:=` or `=`, which makes it harder to see and refactor.

**Example Dream** is what I kind of intuitively would have expected from GO - no nesting, and quick exit without too much verbosity and variable reuse. Obviously it doesn't compile.

Usually `use()` is inlined and repeats the pattern several times, compounding the nesting or split declaration issue.

So what's the most idiomatic way of handling such multiple returns and declarations? Is there a pattern I'm missing?

Comment: In this case it's [example **d**](https://play.golang.org/p/PsTBFzSWQ4) in my opinion. There are some cases where **a** makes sense, **c** less, and **b** is something I try to avoid.

Comment: Take a look at the standard library.

Comment: The idiomatic way to handle your example **D** would look something like this https://play.golang.org/p/HhSF5BXFDb.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you look at lots of Go code you will find the following to be the usual case:

```
func example(data interface{}) (interface{}, error) {
    bytes, err := json.Marshal(data)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    // ... 
    return use(bytes), nil
}
```

The declare and test if construct is nice in its place, but it is not generally apropriate here.

Comment: The problem with this construct is that you have to juggle the operator. You left the triple line operator I intended for the *dream* scenario, but I think that omission is telling - if you were to repeat the construction the compoiler would complain that there are no new variables. I'll edit my question to hopefully explain better.

Comment: It would only complain if you reuse `bytes` as well as `error`, which is very rare in production code. Reusing err is fine and expected, but generally you do no reuse your data values.